# Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i have this script that it takes data from a .txt:

```
public function parse_sigle_item1($filename, $vnum)
{    
    $result = array();
    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    if (($headers = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        //remove all non characters
        $headers = $results = array_map( function ($n) {
            return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $n);
        }, $headers );

        //Get index of vnum
        $vnumIdx = array_search( "VNUM" , $headers);

        if ($headers)
        while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE)
          if ($line)
            if ( sizeof($line)==sizeof($headers) && $line[$vnumIdx] == $vnum )
              $result[ $line[$vnumIdx] ] = array_combine($headers,$line);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return $result;
}
```

My txt headers are like: (tab delimited)

```
VNUM    TYPE    ICON    MODEL
```

and i have two types of lines there the one have `MODEL` and the other one dont have like:

```
1   ETC   test.png   test1
2   ETC   test2.png
```

As you see `VNUM` 2 have no `MODEL` or tab in there...

I need help to fill the `MODE` with 0 or something to not have error like:

> Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

thanks!

Comment: Please add example content of the text file. You should also let us know what happens when you run your code. Do you get errors? If yes, what are they? When do they occur? If no, then what is the issue with your above code?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_pad()` to make sure your data array is the same size as the headers...

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
   if ( $line[$vnumIdx] == $vnum ) {
       $line = array_pad($line, count($headers), 0);
       $result[ $line[$vnumIdx] ] = array_combine($headers,$line);
   }
}
```

You can easily change the value it pads it with, and a possible optimisation would be to store the size of the $headers array rather than fetch it each time.